# How to mask doublequotes in Python when using string replace?

Tags: python

How can mask doublequotes in Python str.replace?

I have the following string in my (JSON) file, and due to invalid JSON i need to replace it.

```
"duration":  ,
```

I need to have

```
"duration": NULL,
```

I tried

```
str.replace(""duration":", "duration": NULL")
str.replace("""duration":"", """duration": NULL"")
```

But nothing worked. What is the correct way?

Comment: You can escape quotes with a backspace, e.g. `\"`.

Comment: Try mixing them with `'` and `"` As python treats them differently
`str.replace('"duration":', '"duration": NULL')`. Note both `'string'` and `"string"` are still same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either wrap your search string in single quotes or escape the double quotes with `\"`

```
str.replace('"duration":', '"duration": NULL')
```

or

```
str.replace("\"duration\":", "\"duration\": NULL")
```